# Saving crypto price values in laravel migration

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I am trying to create a column "amount" which should be able to take little decimal BTC values like 0.0000321, and as well normal int values like 10,15. What migration type can accept these?

Comment: `double ` https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#column-method-double

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In either MySQL or PostgresQL use DECIMAL for any monetary value. It's the only data type which stores as an exact value. FLOAT and DOUBLE are not stored as exact values and aren't good for doing precise math calculations. You can check the documentation on your database of choice for more.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use decimal type. So you can set precision.

Ref:https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#column-method-decimal

> The decimal method creates a DECIMAL equivalent column with the given
> precision (total digits) and scale (decimal digits):

```
$table->decimal('column_name', $precision = 8, $scale = 2);
```